# WordPress add_filter preprocesscomment rating required

Tags: wordpress, rating

Okay I'm looking for a way to make the ratings of comments required, before the user can submit the comment. I am using a an add_filter preprocess_comment, to check if rating isset and to throw a wp_die and stop the upload of the comment. I found a way I think i can do it through the link below. One of my concerns is my rating system and comment approval system are in completely different files. Anyways I tried the code below in my rating system, where it saves the rating. But I keep on get an error try to comment.
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/

```
//in the construct function
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_comment_meta_data');

function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['pixrating'] ) )
        wp_die( __( 'Error: You did not add a rating. Hit the Back    button on your Web browser and resubmit your comment with a rating.' ) );
    return $commentdata;
    }
```

[Rating Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LLSf.png)

Basically I'm just asking is there anything I'm doing wrong, as I'm still kinda new to Word Press and filters.

Edit: I'm not using the exact code found there, I took pieces of it out to work for my code. I'm using the plugin comment-rating found here. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/comments-ratings/

Comment: Can you put your file container these code? please.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry my English. I need reviewer all your code.

Comment: like the pixreview code

Comment: Wait a minute, I'm reproducing this plugin.

Comment: LIke the code where this exists?

Comment: reviewer this post: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/posting-the-same-comment

Comment: Maybe you search on google "duplicate comment detected wordpress plugin line 235"

Answer (score 0):

The code on [www.smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/) is perfectly, I copy and paste all in a file and work fine.

I recommend that you copy and paste this code on `extended-comments.php` file and try again testing.

```html
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Extended Comments
Plugin URI: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: 1.0
Author: Jose Carlos Ramos Carmenates (Copy and paste)
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/

// Add custom meta (ratings) fields to the default comment form
// Default comment form includes name, email address and website URL
// Default comment form elements are hidden when user is logged in

add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'custom_fields');
function custom_fields($fields) {

 $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();
 $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
 $aria_req = ( $req ? " aria-required='true'" : '' );

 $fields[ 'author' ] = '<p class="comment-form-author">'.
                       '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) . '</label>'.
                       ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ).
                       '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="'. esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) .
                       '" size="30" tabindex="1"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';

 $fields[ 'email' ] = '<p class="comment-form-email">'.
                      '<label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label>'.
                      ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ).
                      '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="'. esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) .
                      '" size="30"  tabindex="2"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>';

 $fields[ 'url' ] = '<p class="comment-form-url">'.
                    '<label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>'.
                    '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="'. esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) .
                    '" size="30"  tabindex="3" /></p>';

 $fields[ 'phone' ] = '<p class="comment-form-phone">'.
                      '<label for="phone">' . __( 'Phone' ) . '</label>'.
                      '<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="4" /></p>';

 return $fields;
}


// Add fields after default fields above the comment box, always visible

add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'additional_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'additional_fields' );

function additional_fields () {
 echo '<p class="comment-form-title">'.
      '<label for="title">' . __( 'Comment Title' ) . '</label>'.
      '<input id="title" name="title" type="text" size="30"  tabindex="5" /></p>';

 echo '<p class="comment-form-rating">'.
      '<label for="rating">'. __('Rating') . '<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <span class="commentratingbox">';

 //Current rating scale is 1 to 5. If you want the scale to be 1 to 10, then set the value of $i to 10.
 for( $i=1; $i <= 5; $i++ )
  echo '<span class="commentrating"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="'. $i .'"/>'. $i .'</span>';

 echo'</span></p>';

}



// Save the comment meta data along with comment

add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_comment_meta_data' );
function save_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ) {
 if ( ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) && ( $_POST['phone'] != '') )
  $phone = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['phone']);
 add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone', $phone );

 if ( ( isset( $_POST['title'] ) ) && ( $_POST['title'] != '') )
  $title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title']);
 add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', $title );

 if ( ( isset( $_POST['rating'] ) ) && ( $_POST['rating'] != '') )
  $rating = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['rating']);
 add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
}


// Add the filter to check whether the comment meta data has been filled

add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_comment_meta_data' );
function verify_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {
 if ( ! isset( $_POST['rating'] ) )
  wp_die( __( 'Error: You did not add a rating. Hit the Back button on your Web browser and resubmit your comment with a rating.' ) );
 return $commentdata;
}


// Add an edit option to comment editing screen

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_comment', 'extend_comment_add_meta_box' );
function extend_comment_add_meta_box() {
 add_meta_box( 'title', __( 'Comment Metadata - Extend Comment' ), 'extend_comment_meta_box', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function extend_comment_meta_box ( $comment ) {
 $phone = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'phone', true );
 $title = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'title', true );
 $rating = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
 wp_nonce_field( 'extend_comment_update', 'extend_comment_update', false );
 ?>
 <p>
  <label for="phone"><?php _e( 'Phone' ); ?></label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $phone ); ?>" class="widefat" />
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="title"><?php _e( 'Comment Title' ); ?></label>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" class="widefat" />
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="rating"><?php _e( 'Rating: ' ); ?></label>
      <span class="commentratingbox">
      <?php for( $i=1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
       echo '<span class="commentrating"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="'. $i .'"';
       if ( $rating == $i ) echo ' checked="checked"';
       echo ' />'. $i .' </span>';
      }
      ?>
      </span>
 </p>
 <?php
}

// Update comment meta data from comment editing screen

add_action( 'edit_comment', 'extend_comment_edit_metafields' );

function extend_comment_edit_metafields( $comment_id ) {
 if( ! isset( $_POST['extend_comment_update'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['extend_comment_update'], 'extend_comment_update' ) ) return;

 if ( ( isset( $_POST['phone'] ) ) && ( $_POST['phone'] != '') ) :
  $phone = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['phone']);
  update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone', $phone );
 else :
  delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone');
 endif;

 if ( ( isset( $_POST['title'] ) ) && ( $_POST['title'] != '') ):
  $title = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['title']);
  update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', $title );
 else :
  delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title');
 endif;

 if ( ( isset( $_POST['rating'] ) ) && ( $_POST['rating'] != '') ):
  $rating = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['rating']);
  update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
 else :
  delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating');
 endif;

}
```

I hope help you.